# Emacs rebind self-inserting key

Tags: emacs

On Emacs, Italian keyboard, I'd like the alphanumeric keys above the alphabet (1/!, 2/", 3/£, 4/$, ...) to insert the shifted character (e.g. ! " £ $) when pressed alone.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each number/char pair, you'll need to install two key bindings to swap them, and a third one to avoid messing up the keypad (since the <kbd>kp-0</kbd>-<kbd>kp-9</kbd> keys are translated to <kbd>0</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>, but I guess you don't want <kbd>kp-1</kbd> to insert `!`)

Here is a macro to avoid creating all those key bindings by hand:

```lisp
(defmacro swap-keys (list)
  `(progn
     ,@(mapcar
        (lambda (keys)
          (let ((key1 (car keys))
                (key2 (cdr keys)))
            `(progn
               (global-set-key ,key1 (lambda () (interactive) (insert ,key2)))
               (global-set-key ,key2 (lambda () (interactive) (insert ,key1)))
               (global-set-key (kbd ,(format "<kp-%s>" key1))
                               (lambda () (interactive) (insert ,key1))))))
        list)))

(swap-keys (("1" . "!")
            ("2" . "\"")))
```

Comment: Thanks Francesco! I managed to do the remapping at X-server level, but your code seem interesting!

Answer (score 4):

You can set up a custom input method that has those keys flipped ([doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Input-Method.html)).

ex I have this in my .emacs for the layout I use:

```
(eval-after-load 'quail
  '(progn
      (add-to-list 'quail-keyboard-layout-alist
     '("us-pgr-dvk" . "\
                              \
$~&%[7{5}3(1=9*0)2+4]6!8#`    \
  ;:,<.>pPyYfFgGcCrRlL/?@^\\|  \
  aAoOeEuUiIdDhHtTnNsS-_      \
  '\"qQjJkKxXbBmMwWvVzZ        \
                              "))
   ))
(quail-set-keyboard-layout "us-pgr-dvk")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "1") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "!")))
```

etc.

Comment: or indeed `(global-set-key (kbd "1") "!")`; however the other answers are more comprehensive.